# Flip and crop a bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I'm getting a bytearray (32 bit or 16 bit) from a source.

If the size width is odd, the last pixel in each row needs to be dropped.
If the height is odd, the last row needs to be dropped.
If the height is negative the bitmap needs to be flipped vertically.

Here is my code so far:

```
m_pbmiLast = new BITMAPINFO(*m_pbmi);
m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biWidth = abs(m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biWidth) - (abs(m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biWidth) % 2);
m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biHeight = abs(m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biHeight) - (abs(m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biHeight) % 2);

int biWidth = m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biWidth;
int biHeight = m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biHeight;
int iAdjustedStride = ((((biWidth * m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);
int iRealStride = ((((m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);


if (m_pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight < 0) {
    /* Copy the actual data */
    int iLineOffsetSource = 0;
    int iLineOffsetDest = (biHeight - 1) * iRealStride;
    for (int i = 0; i < biHeight; ++i) {
        memcpy(&pData[iLineOffsetDest], &m_inputBuffer[iLineOffsetSource], iAdjustedStride);
        iLineOffsetSource += iRealStride;
        iLineOffsetDest -= iRealStride;
    }
} else {
    int iLineOffset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < biHeight; ++i) {
        memcpy(&pData[iLineOffset], &m_inputBuffer[iLineOffset], iAdjustedStride);
        iLineOffset += iRealStride;
    }
}
```

It doesn't flip the bitmap, and when the bitmap is an odd width, it slants the bitmap.

Comment: Try negating `m_pbmiLast->bmiHeader.biHeight` and see if that helps with the flipping. Also I suspect you meant to initialise `biWidth` to the original bitmap width, not the new one.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with making the height negative when using WinAPI (didn't work for me on Linux). As for flipping the pixels manually, this code is absolutely awful. Why do you create a `new BITMAPINFO`. This isn't Java where you allocate on the heap for sport.

Comment: @Brandon I create a new BITMAPINFO because in between being called, the old bitmap info can change.  Just before this code, i check that none of the values have changed between calls.  In between calls the height/width event the BitCount can change.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The output of this is fed into x264, which does not take a negative height, part of the purpose of this code is to scrub the bitmap to make it suitable for x264

Comment: It looks to me like you're using the wrong strides for the destination and source offsets. Rename them `iDestStride` and `iInputStride` or something like that to eliminate confusion.

Comment: @MarkRansom  Thanks, it works now, after sorting out which strides to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done like so.. I include the reading and writing just to make it an SSCCE. It has little to no error.

As for my comment about `new BITMAPINFO`. I was saying that you don't have to allocate such a small structure on the HEAP. Ditch the `new` part. The only allocation you need for a bitmap is the pixels. The header and other info does not need an allocation at all.

See the `Flip` function below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#include <windows.h>

typedef struct
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER Header;
    BITMAPINFO Info;
    unsigned char* Pixels;
} BITMAPDATA;

void LoadBmp(const char* path, BITMAPDATA* Data)
{
    std::ifstream hFile(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if(hFile.is_open())
    {
        hFile.read((char*)&Data->Header, sizeof(Data->Header));
        hFile.read((char*)&Data->Info, sizeof(Data->Info));
        hFile.seekg(Data->Header.bfOffBits, std::ios::beg);

        Data->Pixels = new unsigned char[Data->Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
        hFile.read((char*)Data->Pixels, Data->Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
        hFile.close();
    }
}

void SaveBmp(const char* path, BITMAPDATA* Data)
{
    std::ofstream hFile(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    if (hFile.is_open())
    {
        hFile.write((char*)&Data->Header, sizeof(Data->Header));
        hFile.write((char*)&Data->Info, sizeof(Data->Info));
        hFile.seekp(Data->Header.bfOffBits, std::ios::beg);

        hFile.write((char*)Data->Pixels, Data->Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
        hFile.close();
    }
}

void Flip(BITMAPDATA* Data)
{
    unsigned short bpp = Data->Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount;
    unsigned int width = std::abs(Data->Info.bmiHeader.biWidth);
    unsigned int height = std::abs(Data->Info.bmiHeader.biHeight);

    unsigned char* out = new unsigned char[Data->Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
    unsigned long chunk = (bpp > 24 ? width * 4 : width * 3 + width % 4);

    unsigned char* dst = out;
    unsigned char* src = Data->Pixels + chunk * (height - 1);

    while(src != Data->Pixels)
    {
        std::memcpy(dst, src, chunk);
        dst += chunk;
        src -= chunk;
    }

    std::memcpy(dst, src, chunk); //for 24-bit.
    std::swap(Data->Pixels, out);
    delete[] out;
}


int main()
{
    BITMAPDATA Data;
    LoadBmp("C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Bar.bmp", &Data);
    Flip(&Data);
    SaveBmp("C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Foo.bmp", &Data);
    delete[] Data.Pixels;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) is a viable alternative, that already provides the requested bitmap [transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719656.aspx#_bitmaptransforms).

Comment: [PlgBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-plgblt) can flip a device dependent bitmap, then for a right/bottom crop, use BitBlt source co-ords, else for left/top crop, "_BitBlt only does clipping on the destination DC_".